# Integration over the intersection of a hypersphere and half spaces

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $0<c<\Vert u\Vert$, how could I compute (or find the upper bound of) the following integral
$$\int_{x^\top x =1,~\vert u^\top x\vert\leq c}1dx.$$

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: For a unit vector $x$ you obtain $\left|u^\intercal x\right| = ||u||\cdot|\cos(\theta)|\leq c$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $x$. What does the restriction $\theta\in\left[ \arccos(c/||u||),\pi\right]$ mean for the integral over the sphere $S_{n-1}$?